# How to prepare a dataset for Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

### Motivation

To run a set of labeled vectors through [Keras](http://keras.io/) neural network.

### Example

Looking at Keras dataset example mnist:

```
keras.datasets import mnist
(x_tr, y_tr), (x_te, y_te) = mnist.load_data()
print x_tr.shape
```

It seem to be a 3 dimensional numpy array:

```
(60000, 28, 28)
```

- 1st dimension is for the samples
- 2nd and 3rd for each sample features

### Attempt

Building the labeled vectors:

```
X_train = numpy.array([[1] * 128] * (10 ** 4) + [[0] * 128] * (10 ** 4))
X_test = numpy.array([[1] * 128] * (10 ** 2) + [[0] * 128] * (10 ** 2))

Y_train = numpy.array([True] * (10 ** 4) + [False] * (10 ** 4))
Y_test = numpy.array([True] * (10 ** 2) + [False] * (10 ** 2))

X_train = X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")

Y_train = Y_train.astype("bool")
Y_test = Y_test.astype("bool")
```

### The training code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, 50))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, 50))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, 1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

rms = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=rms)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          show_accuracy=True, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, show_accuracy=True, verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

### Result

```
Test score: 13.9705320154
Test accuracy: 1.0
```

Why do I get such a bad result for such a simple dataset?
Is my dataset malformed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A softmax over just one output node doesn't make much sense. If you change `model.add(Activation('softmax'))` to `model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))`, your network performs well.

Alternatively you can also use two output nodes, where `1, 0` represents the case of `True` and `0, 1` represents the case of `False`. Then you can use a softmax layer. You just have to change your `Y_train` and `Y_test` accordingly.

Comment: @c0d3rman "if you put 5, 6, 7 through softmax, you'll get each divided by their sum - 5 / 18, 6 / 18, 7 / 18". That is not correct. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function